# Declare a textbox as a global variable so it can be reused

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am creating a WBS diagram in Excel using VBA. The diagram would consists of multiple blocks of text from a main worksheet. I have created a textbox using a macro.

I would be using this textbox multiple times. Is it possible to assign a variable and reuse it?

Comment: Do you mean a global variable?

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: What do you mean by `Box`?

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: @DiMono & Gary: Unfortunately I cannot post the code as it is on my working laptop and I do not have access to it till next Monday. I will however put it as soon as I have it.

Comment: @Siddharth: By box I mean a sort of text box with 4 rows each consisting of a different set of attributes. How can I reuse this is my question.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, I mean a global variable that can be reused all over the code.

Comment: You can certainly use globals, and reference them from other modules if necessary.  But we'll need to see your code to understand how to intend to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a global variable put this at the top of the module just below Option Explicit: `Dim shp As Shape`

Then try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim shp As Shape

Sub getTextbox()

    Dim myShapes As Shapes
    Set myShapes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes

    For Each shp In myShapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            Debug.Print shp.Name
            Debug.Print shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
            shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello World!"

            'exit upon finding the right text box to
            If shp.Name = "TextBox 2" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub testName()
    Debug.Print shp.Name
End Sub
```

You are looking for shapes which include many things that can be on a worksheet. Then test each to see if it is the right type. You could also test by name.

Then run the sub TestName and it should still have the textbox in memory.